# How can I show the Inspector window in the Editor Window at the same size?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is that in the Inspector it looks fine as I wanted but in the Editor Window the controls and fields not in the same positions.

In the screenshot the Inspector window is on the right the Editor Window on the left. The problem is with the Conversation Name on the Inspector the name field is right after the Conversation Name but in the Editor Window the name field seems to be a bit over the Conversation Name :

[image: Conversation Name]

This is the editor script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ConversationTrigger))]
public class ConversationTriggerEditor : Editor
{
    private ConversationTrigger _conversationTrigger;

    [SerializeField] private ReorderableList conversationsList;

    private SerializedProperty _conversations;

    private int _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = -1;
    private int newSize = 0;
    private Vector2 scrollPos;
    private SerializedProperty conversationsCounter;

    private readonly Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _dialoguesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _sentencesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _conversationTrigger = (ConversationTrigger)target;
        _conversations = serializedObject.FindProperty("conversations");

        conversationsList = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, _conversations)
        {
            displayAdd = true,
            displayRemove = true,
            draggable = true,

            drawHeaderCallback = DrawConversationsHeader,

            drawElementCallback = DrawConversationsElement,

            onAddCallback = (list) =>
            {
                SerializedProperty addedElement;
                // if something is selected add after that element otherwise on the end
                if (_currentlySelectedConversationIndex >= 0)
                {
                    list.serializedProperty.InsertArrayElementAtIndex(_currentlySelectedConversationIndex + 1);
                    addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(_currentlySelectedConversationIndex + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    list.serializedProperty.arraySize++;
                    addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(list.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1);
                }

                var name = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                var foldout = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
                var dialogues = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Dialogues");

                name.stringValue = "";
                foldout.boolValue = false;
                dialogues.arraySize = 0;

                conversationsCounter = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("ConversationIndex");
            },

            elementHeightCallback = (index) =>
            {
                return GetConversationHeight(_conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index));
            }
        };
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        // if there are no elements reset _currentlySelectedConversationIndex
        if (conversationsList.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1 < _currentlySelectedConversationIndex) _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = -1;

        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Conversations", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        {
            newSize = EditorGUILayout.IntField(_conversations.arraySize);
        }
        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            if (newSize > _conversations.arraySize)
            {
                // elements have to be added -> how many?
                var toAdd = newSize - _conversations.arraySize - 1;
                // why -1 ? -> We add the first element and set its values to default
                // now if we simply increase the arraySize for the rest of the elements
                // they will be all a copy of the first -> all defaults ;)

                // first add one element
                _conversations.arraySize++;
                // then get that element
                var newIndex = _conversations.arraySize - 1;
                var newElement = _conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(newIndex);

                // now reset all properties like
                var name = newElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                name.stringValue = "";

                // now for the rest simply increase arraySize
                _conversations.arraySize += toAdd;
            }
            else
            {
                // for removing just make sure the arraySize is not under 0
                _conversations.arraySize = Mathf.Max(newSize, 0);
            }
        }

        scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Height(250));

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        conversationsList.DoLayoutList();

        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Save Conversations"))
        {
            _conversationTrigger.SaveConversations();
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Load Conversations"))
        {
            Undo.RecordObject(_conversationTrigger, "Loaded conversations from JSON");
            _conversationTrigger.LoadConversations();
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    #region Drawers

    #region List Headers

    private void DrawConversationsHeader(Rect rect)
    {
        //EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, "Conversations");
    }

    private void DrawDialoguesHeader(Rect rect)
    {
        EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, "Dialogues");
    }

    private void DrawSentencesHeader(Rect rect)
    {
        EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, "Sentences");
    }

    #endregion List Headers

    #region Elements

    private void DrawConversationsElement(Rect rect, int index, bool isActive, bool isFocused)
    {
        if (isActive) _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = index;

        var conversation = _conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

        var position = new Rect(rect);

        var name = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
        var foldout = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
        var dialogues = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Dialogues");
        string dialoguesListKey = conversation.propertyPath;

        EditorGUI.indentLevel++;
        {
            // make the label be a foldout
            //GUI.TextField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, 15, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), itemscounter.ToString());
            foldout.boolValue = EditorGUI.Foldout(new Rect(position.x, position.y, 10, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), foldout.boolValue, "Conversation Name ", true);
            name.stringValue = EditorGUI.TextField(new Rect(position.x + 120, position.y, 244, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), name.stringValue);

            if (foldout.boolValue)
            {
                // draw the name field
                //name.stringValue = EditorGUI.TextField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), name.stringValue);
                position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

                if (!_dialoguesListDict.ContainsKey(dialoguesListKey))
                {
                    // create reorderabl list and store it in dict
                    var dialoguesList = new ReorderableList(conversation.serializedObject, dialogues)
                    {
                        displayAdd = true,
                        displayRemove = true,
                        draggable = true,

                        drawHeaderCallback = DrawDialoguesHeader,

                        drawElementCallback = (convRect, convIndex, convActive, convFocused) => { DrawDialoguesElement(_dialoguesListDict[dialoguesListKey], convRect, convIndex, convActive, convFocused); },

                        elementHeightCallback = (dialogIndex) =>
                        {
                            return GetDialogueHeight(_dialoguesListDict[dialoguesListKey].serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(dialogIndex));
                        },

                        onAddCallback = (list) =>
                        {
                            list.serializedProperty.arraySize++;
                            var addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(list.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1);

                            var newDialoguesName = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                            var newDialoguesFoldout = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
                            var sentences = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Sentences");

                            newDialoguesName.stringValue = "";
                            newDialoguesFoldout.boolValue = true;
                            sentences.arraySize = 0;
                        }
                    };
                    _dialoguesListDict[dialoguesListKey] = dialoguesList;
                }

                _dialoguesListDict[dialoguesListKey].DoList(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, position.height - EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight));
            }

        }
        EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
    }

    private void DrawDialoguesElement(ReorderableList list, Rect rect, int index, bool isActive, bool isFocused)
    {
        if (list == null) return;

        var dialog = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

        var position = new Rect(rect);

        var foldout = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
        var name = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Name");

        {
            // make the label be a foldout
            foldout.boolValue = EditorGUI.Foldout(new Rect(position.x, position.y, 10, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), foldout.boolValue, foldout.boolValue ? "" : name.stringValue);

            var sentencesListKey = dialog.propertyPath;
            var sentences = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Sentences");

            if (foldout.boolValue)
            {
                // draw the name field
                name.stringValue = EditorGUI.TextField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), name.stringValue);
                position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

                if (!_sentencesListDict.ContainsKey(sentencesListKey))
                {
                    // create reorderabl list and store it in dict
                    var sentencesList = new ReorderableList(sentences.serializedObject, sentences)
                    {
                        displayAdd = true,
                        displayRemove = true,
                        draggable = true,

                        // header for the dialog list
                        drawHeaderCallback = DrawSentencesHeader,

                        // how a sentence is displayed
                        drawElementCallback = (sentenceRect, sentenceIndex, sentenceIsActive, sentenceIsFocused) =>
                        {
                            var sentence = sentences.GetArrayElementAtIndex(sentenceIndex);

                            // draw simple textArea for sentence
                            sentence.stringValue = EditorGUI.TextArea(sentenceRect, sentence.stringValue);
                        },

                        // Sentences have simply a fixed height of 2 lines
                        elementHeight = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 2,

                        // when a sentence is added
                        onAddCallback = (sentList) =>
                        {
                            sentList.serializedProperty.arraySize++;
                            var addedElement = sentList.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(sentList.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1);

                            addedElement.stringValue = "";
                        }
                    };

                    // store the created ReorderableList
                    _sentencesListDict[sentencesListKey] = sentencesList;
                }

                // Draw the list
                _sentencesListDict[sentencesListKey].DoList(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, position.height - EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight));
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion Elements

    #endregion Drawers


    #region Helpers

    #region HeightGetter

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the height of given Conversation property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="conversation"></param>
    /// <returns>height of given Conversation property</returns>
    private float GetConversationHeight(SerializedProperty conversation)
    {
        var foldout = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");

        // if not foldout the height is simply 1 line
        var height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

        // otherwise we sum up every controls and child heights
        if (foldout.boolValue)
        {
            // we need some more lines:
            //  for the Name field,
            // the list header,
            // the list buttons and a bit buffer
            height += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 5;


            var dialogues = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Dialogues");

            for (var d = 0; d < dialogues.arraySize; d++)
            {
                var dialog = dialogues.GetArrayElementAtIndex(d);
                height += GetDialogueHeight(dialog);
            }
        }

        return height;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the height of given Dialogue property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dialog"></param>
    /// <returns>height of given Dialogue property</returns>
    private float GetDialogueHeight(SerializedProperty dialog)
    {
        var foldout = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");

        // same game for the dialog if not foldout it is only a single line
        var height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

        // otherwise sum up controls and child heights
        if (foldout.boolValue)
        {
            // we need some more lines:
            //  for the Name field,
            // the list header,
            // the list buttons and a bit buffer
            height += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 4;

            var sentences = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Sentences");

            // the sentences are easier since they always have the same height
            // in this example 2 lines so simply do
            // at least have space for 1 sentences even if there is none
            height += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * Mathf.Max(1, sentences.arraySize) * 2;
        }

        return height;
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion Helpers
}
```

This is the part where I add the Conversation Name and the name field :

```
foldout.boolValue = EditorGUI.Foldout(new Rect(position.x, position.y, 10, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), foldout.boolValue, "Conversation Name ", true);
name.stringValue = EditorGUI.TextField(new Rect(position.x + 120, position.y, 244, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), name.stringValue);
```

And this is the Editor Window script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

public class ConversationsEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    private ConversationTriggerEditor editor;

    [MenuItem("Conversations/Conversations System")]
    static void Init()
    {
        const int width = 800;
        const int height = 800;

        var x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        var y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        var window = GetWindow<ConversationsEditorWindow>();
        var ff = FindObjectOfType<ConversationTrigger>();
        window.position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
        window.editor = (ConversationTriggerEditor)Editor.CreateEditor(ff);
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        editor.OnInspectorGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: The difference seems to be that in the Inspector `position` refers to the `Rect` in which the according field/property is displayed. In the EditorWindow as you can see it starts at the top-left corner while in the Inspector you have a bit of an offset around. Then for the `Conversation Name` label in the EditorWindow there is also a little offset between label/foldout and the grib icon of the ReorderableList .. don't know how to fix this though

Comment: You could try and wrap the `editor.OnInspectorGUI()` in `EditorGUI.indentLevel++;` and `EditorGUI.indentLevel--;`